# Why the Cesàro operator $(Cf)(s) = \frac{1}{s}\int_0^sf(t)dt$ on $L^2(0,\infty)$ is not compact?

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, compact-operators

By Hardy's inequality, $C$ is bounded. But I find no way to prove it to be noncompact. I was thinking about its adjoint
$$
(C^\ast f)(s) = \int_x^\infty\frac{1}{t}f(t)dt
$$

But I'm afraid it is equally difficult to show that $C^\ast$ is noncompact. So this approach does not work.

I also attempted to use a classic sequence on the unit ball: $f_n = \chi_{[n,n+1]}$. But it turned out to be a monster. Indeed we have $\lVert f_n \rVert = 1$ and $\lVert f_m-f_n \rVert = \sqrt{2}\delta_{mn}$, which is pretty neat. But computing the norm of $Cf_n$ and $C(f_m-f_n)$ is a disaster:
$$
\lVert Cf_n \rVert = \sqrt{2-2n\ln\left( 1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)} \\
\lVert C(f_m-f_n) \rVert =\sqrt{\frac{2n+1}{n+1}-2n\ln\left( 1+\frac{1}{n}\right)+2+\frac{1}{m}-2(m+1)\ln\left( 1+\frac{1}{m}\right)+\ln\frac{m}{n+1}}
$$
provided $m>n$ (hopefully my calculation wasn't wrong!). With these being said, is there any accessible way to prove the noncompactness (whether direct or indirect)? I guess I found two inaccessible way (or maybe not as I didn't realise how to use it). Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to show that the Hardy transform $H:f\mapsto\frac1t\int^t_0f$ as an operator on $L_p(0,\infty)$, where  $1<p<\infty$, is not compact. Consider the family of functions $\{\phi_A(x)=A^{1/p}\mathbf{1}_{(0,1/A]}(x): A>0\}$. We have that
$$\|\phi_A\|_p=1$$
and
$$G_A(x):=(H\phi_A)(x)=\frac1x\int^x_0\phi_A = A^{1/p}\Big(\mathbf{1}_{(0,1/A]}(x) + \frac{1}{Ax}\mathbf{1}_{(1/A,\infty)}(x)\Big)$$
Then, for $A<B$,
$$\begin{align}
 |G_A - G_B|&=\big(B^{1/p}-A^{1/p}\big)\mathbb{1}_{(0,1/B]}(x)+\left|\frac{B^{1-\tfrac1p}}{x}- A^{1/p}\right|\mathbb{1}_{(1/B,1/A]}(x) \\
&\qquad + \big(A^{\tfrac1p -1} -B^{\tfrac1p -1}\big)\frac{1}{x}\mathbb{1}_{(1/A,\infty)}(x)\\
&\geq \big(A^{\tfrac1p -1} -B^{\tfrac1p -1}\big)\frac{1}{x}\mathbf{1}_{(1/A,\infty)}(x)
\end{align}$$
whence we conclude that
$$\|G_A - G_B\|_p \geq \frac{1}{(p-1)^{1/p}}\left|1-(A/B)^{1-\frac1p}\right|$$
It follows that $\{g_n=\phi_{2^n}:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is sequence in unit ball in $L_p(0,\infty)$ for which  $\{Hg_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ has no convergent subsequence in $L_p(0,\infty)$.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I'm afraid maybe there is something wrong with this reply... For example your definition of $G_A$ is wrong as the integration should be $(0,x]$ instead of $(0,\infty)$. Do consider review and correct the answer so that it's helpful for not only me but also many others!

Comment: I have another question: Is it legit here to consider $1/(1-p)^{1/p}$? Since $p>1$ we would get an imaginary number...

Comment: Sorry to take your time but I still have some trouble. If we put $A=4$, $B=9$, $p=2$ and $x=1/6$, then $G_A(x)=G_B(x)=2$. But $\frac{1}{B} < x < \frac{1}{A}$, hence $|G_A-G_B|< |\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3}| \cdot 6 = 1$. The crutial inequality is not correct. (If I'm wrong, just correct me!)

Comment: If I'm right we have
$$
G_A-G_B=\left(\sqrt{B}-\sqrt{A} \right)\chi_{(0,1/B]}(x)+\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{B}x}-\sqrt{A}\right)\chi_{(1/B,1/A]}(x)
        +\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{B}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{A}} \right)\frac{1}{x}\chi_{(1/A,+\infty)}(x)
$$
Hence we can only get $|G_A-G_B| \geq \left|\frac{1}{\sqrt{B}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{A}} \right|\frac{1}{x}\chi_{(1/A,+\infty)}(x)$. An important thing is that $\frac{1}{A}>\frac{1}{B}$.

Comment: I think things are clear now: the family of functions you gave indeed does the trick, but there are two remaining typos. First of all we should write
$$
|G_A - G_B|\geq \big|A^{1/p -1} -B^{1/p -1}|\frac{1}{x}\mathbf{1}_{(1/{\color\red{A}},\infty)}(x).
$$
And the result should be
$$
\|G_A - G_B\|_p \geq \frac{1}{(p-1)^{1/p}}\left|1-({\color\red{A/B}})^{1-\frac1p}\right|.
$$
If you agree with my correction, do consider edit it (I'm afraid I can't do it due to character restriction) to prevent future confusion for other people working on this problem, many thanks!

Comment: Still if we take the example that $(A,B,p)=(4,9,2)$, we have $B^{1/p-1}=1/3 < A^{1/p-1}=1/2$. Also I offered an counterexample when $x=1/6$, you can scroll up a little bit.

Comment: @ZoeDesvl: I added more details in the derivation of the inequality concerning $|G_A-G_B|$ ($0<A<B$). You were correct and I made s silly mistake before. I hope this is it!